# Freemarker Template Not Found in Dropwizard Intellij

Tags: java, freemarker, dropwizard, dropwizard-templates

I'm trying to set up a freemarker template to show the results of a SQL query. I'm running into an issue where Intellij is reporting that the template cannot be found:

```
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,623] freemarker.cache: Couldn't find template in cache for "com/example/www/resources/template.ftl"("en_US", ISO-8859-1, parsed); will try to load it.
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,624] freemarker.cache: TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("com/example/www/resources/template_en_US.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,626] freemarker.cache: TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("com/example/www/resources/template_en.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,627] freemarker.cache: TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("com/example/www/resources/template.ftl"): Not found
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,661] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHttpOutputInterceptor@f62788 exclude by status 404
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,662] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: sendResponse info=null content=HeapByteBuffer@d1e062[p=0,l=248,c=32768,r=248]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<me.../body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} complete=true committing=true callback=Blocker@4fab4a{null}
DEBUG [2018-02-27 18:52:31,662] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: COMMIT for /address/3 on HttpChannelOverHttp@a67c6b{r=1,c=true,a=DISPATCHED,uri=//localhost:8080/address/3}
404 Not Found HTTP/1.1
Date: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 18:52:31 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
```

This happened when my main method in my app class was set up like so:

```
public class AppApplication extends Application<AppConfiguration> {

     public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

         new AppApplication().run(args);
}
```

Under this setup, navigating to the URL that returns an address database returns a 404 error in my browser and the above logs in debug mode.

Additional research into using Freemarker in Dropwizard led me to setting up a Configuration instance in the main method of the app to look for the template with setDirectoryForTemplateLoading, to point to the path, and to use getTemplate to return the template file itself:

```
public class AppApplication extends Application<AppConfiguration> {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_27);

        cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("C:\\IdeaProjects\\App\\src\\main\\resources"));
        cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");

        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER);

        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);

        cfg.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);

        new AppApplication().run(args);
    }
```

However, going to the URL returns the same error.  The only discernible difference in this case is that the info for the error is printed at the top of the console as the server starts:

```
14:09:24.891 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Couldn't find template in cache for "template.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
14:09:24.907 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template_en_US.ftl"): Not found
14:09:24.907 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template_en.ftl"): Not found
14:09:24.907 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template.ftl"): Found
14:09:24.922 [main] DEBUG freemarker.cache - Loading template for "template.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from "C:\\IdeaProjects\\App\\src\\main\\resources\\template.ftl"
```

At the end, it shows that is it loading the template from the resource folder;  However, trying to run the getter methods I've defined returns the same error later on in the console. Can anyone give me some insight on this? I don't think its an issue with my code, but rather that the .ftl file isn't regestering to Intellij.

Edit: Here is my View Bundle, under initialize.:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle<AppConfiguration>() {
            public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getViewConfiguration(AppConfiguration configuration) {
                return configuration.getViewRendererConfiguration();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just checking, you did add the Viewbundle to your application?

Comment: Yes, under initialize.  I followed the Dropwizard 1.2.2 documentation.

Comment: Regarding your experiment with creating the `Configuration` manually, as you don't pass that `Configuration` instance to Dropwizard, of course it has no effect on it. But certainly you should solve this with Dropwizard's default `TemplateLoader` anyway.

Comment: Your template paths in the real case are quite strange (`com/example/www/resources/template.ftl`). With the Dropwizard default `TemplateLoader`, I believe that template should be at `src/main/resources/com/example/www/resources/template.ftl` in the source code. Is it there? Or, is that really where you want it to be?

Comment: I realize this is going to sound dumb, but is the default TemplateLoader one I call or does Dropwizard use it automatically?  I didn't see any mention of it in the Views documentation on the site.